# Error While creating Custom JWT Token using Firebase

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, firebase, jwt

I am trying to setup user Authentication for my .net Web API using Firebase. I saw a tutorial that shows how to generate a jwt token from a uri, but I want to add my own claims. so I tried to create my own token after I checked if the user email and password are correct. Each time  I try to use the custom token I get this error :
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found"

here is my function to generate the token :

```
public async Task<string> GetForCredentialsAsync(string email, string password)
    {
        var request = new
        {
            email,
            password,
            returnSecureToken = true,
        };
        
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("", request);
        
        var authToken = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthToken>();
        
        if (authToken == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid email or password");
        }
        
        var additionalClaims = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"email", email},
            { "Role", "Admin" },
        };
        
        var customToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateCustomTokenAsync(authToken.LocalId, additionalClaims);

        return customToken;
    }
```

and here is my config:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["Firebase:Iss"];
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["Firebase:Iss"],
                    ValidAudience = configuration["Firebase:aud"],

                };
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            });
```

I tried to change the Issuer , Audience and Authority but nothing worked